# cordova.exec() ios once execution error

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm making an iOS app with phonegap, I have a native part and another phonegap part.
I want to fill a textfield with data saved in NSUserDefaults. First time I try this, it's ok, but in the other times nothing happends, the iOS method to get data saved in NSUserDefaults never is called.

this is my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *text = @"";
    if ([defaults valueForKey:@"mText"] != nil) {
        text = [defaults valueForKey:@"mText"];
    }

    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"mText\":\"%@\" }", text];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);

    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"OK"];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

And in the js File:

```
getTextData: function (successCallBack, errorCallBack){
        cordova.exec(successCallBack, errorCallBack, "MyData", "getTextData", []);
    }
```

In this post I have found the solution of my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24906634/4116026

I add this two lines to the bottom of cordova.js:

```
var exec = cordova.require('cordova/exec');
exec.setJsToNativeBridgeMode(exec.jsToNativeModes.IFRAME_NAV);
```

It works perfectly!
Thanks for all

Comment: open you desktop safari and debug the app to see if something is failing

Comment: On safari Works perfectly :(

Comment: What did you do? I didn't mean to open your app in safari (BTW, that shouldn't work), I meant, execute your app on the phone while you debug it with desktop safari http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: Yes, I debug it and works fine, but whent should execute cordova.exec nothing happend, the objective-c method never is called

Comment: Can you upload the plugin to github so I can take a look and try it?

Comment: I edit the question because I have found the solution of the problem, thanks!

Comment: then, are you using an old version? that should be fixed by now. Be careful, apps built with old cordova versions can't be submitted to the apple store.

Comment: Yes friend! The problem appeared because I used a cordova old version, when I updated to last version, the problem dissapeared